# Advanced Custom Fields in WooCommerce Email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

I am using [Advanced Custom Fields *(ACF)* plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) in WooCommerce and I have set a custom field named "tracking-no".

How can I display the value of this custom field in the Woocommerce template `emails/customer-completed-order.php`?

I am using this code:

```
<?php
    if(get_field('tracking-no'))
    {
        echo '<p>' . get_field('tracking-no') . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

But I doesn't get anything.

Thanks

Comment: **Updated my answer:** There was a missing **`;`** and added compatibility for prior versions of WooCommerce…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your WooCommerce template you should get first the order ID as argument in [**`get_field()`**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/):

```
<?php
    $tracking_num = get_field('tracking-no', $order->get_id() );

    if( $tracking_num ){
        echo '<p>' . $tracking_num . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

---

You can also use instead any email notification hook that you can find on this template, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_custom_field_in_completed_notification', 10, 4 );
function my_custom_field_in_completed_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $tracking_num = get_field('tracking-no', $order->get_id() );

    if( $tracking_num ){
        echo '<p>' . $tracking_num . '</p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).*

> In this case we don't override WooCommerce templates. You can also use that 2 similar hooks:
>
> ```
> 'woocommerce_email_order_meta'
> 'woocommerce_email_customer_details'
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. Seems to be the right way. But It is not working and even getting

 $order_id = int_val( $order->id );

results an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After your good starting point finally this did the job:

<?php

$myOrderID = $order->id;
$tracking   = get_field('track-no', $myOrderID);

?>

<?php if( get_field('track-no', $myOrderID) ): ?>

<p><?php _e("Your tracking ID: ", 'savoy'); ?>
<?php 
echo "<a href='https://www.deutschepost.de/sendung/simpleQueryResult.html?form.sendungsnummer=" . $tracking . "' target='_blank'>" . $tracking . "</a>"; ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>